# Local binding to an OpenCMIS server using Apache Chemistry

Tags: java, cmis, apache-chemistry

first of all, I'd appreciate if anybody could add "apache-chemistry" tag, I have not enough mana for that.

I can't find any information on **[this](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/examples/example-create-session.html)** local binding, it's the third way of connecting to an OpenCMIS server.

It's the case when one wants to have a shared access layer to a remote repository and a JCR repository running locally, for example. It's obvious how the remote setup works, but I don't understand what this mean:

```
parameter.put(SessionParameter.LOCAL_FACTORY, "my.local.factory");
```

EDITED: In the meantime I found it could be the repository connector, into which the data from CMIS clients are converted and pushed, but I'm not sure...

> A repository connector has to extend
>   the AbstractServiceFactory class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's complicated to explain, I suppose that the best thing to do is checking out [inMemoryServer](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/chemistry/opencmis/trunk/chemistry-opencmis-server/chemistry-opencmis-server-inmemory) from SVN. The documentation you referenced is an example of Client API, where the session interface contain the most important CMIS operations.

```
SessionFactory factory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<String, String>();
..........
parameter.put(SessionParameter.LOCAL_FACTORY, "my.local.factory");
..........
Session session = factory.createSession(parameter);
```

After you have the source, take a look at "InMemoryServiceFactoryImpl" which is the `LOCAL_FACTORY` parameter value. This factory has a `service()` method that returns `InMemoryService`, which holds references to all types of CMIS services and it servers as some sort of facade for simplified using via the Client API (Session way).

Another way is using Client Binding API, where you access concrete CMIS services directly.

```
CmisBindingFactory factory = CmisBindingFactory.newInstance();
CmisBinding binding = factory.createCmisLocalBinding(parameters); // LocalBinding !!
fFactory = binding.getObjectFactory();
fRepSvc = binding.getRepositoryService();
fObjSvc = binding.getObjectService();
fNavSvc = binding.getNavigationService();
fVerSvc = binding.getVersioningService();
fMultiSvc = binding.getMultiFilingService();
fDiscSvc = binding.getDiscoveryService();
```

etc., etc., take a look at the tests, which practically cover most of the use cases.

Answer (score 1):

It is supposed to be the

> Class name of the local service
>   factory if client and server reside
>   in the same JVM

See **Creating a Local binding instance** [here](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/examples/example-create-session.html) and description for LOCAL_FACTORY [here](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis-session-parameters.html)

Comment: amol, wouldn't you happen to have more information on this ? This is practically what I said ... What to do next ? After I implement AbstractServiceFactory ... it's like that this method CmisService getService(CallContext context) is called by the CMIS client, all the server side stuff is done there I suppose ... What the client should do ? I don't get it ... I get the real client server model, not this

Comment: ok, at first I thought you question was more basic but if it is "how do I expose and then access a local JCR repository using OpenCMIS/Chemistry", I don't think the answer is straight forward (yet). see http://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis-jcr-repository.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to have an [OpenCMIS server implementation](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/dev-server.html) to use the local binding. If there is one, pass the class name of the service factory and the client will use it. It will call the services (Java interfaces) directly without sending data over the network. There is nothing else to do on the client side.